# What the terms "basis functions" and "orthogonal" denote in the case of signals?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, harmonic-analysis, signal-processing

I am a beginer. I have read that any
given signal whether it is simple or
complex one,can be represented as
summation of orthogonal basis
functions.

Here, what the terms **Orthogonal** and
**Basis function** denote in case of
signals?

Answer (score 5):

It means the same things that for "usual" vectors.

- Two vectors $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal if $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$

With functions, the inner product is usually (for real valued functions)

$$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{\Omega} f(x) g(x) dx$$

- A familly $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ of vectors from $E$ is a basis if

  - every vector of $E$ can be written as a finite linear combinaison of some $x_i$
  - the vectors $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ are lineary independants : if $\sum_{k=1}^n a_i x_{\sigma(i)} = 0$ then $a_1 = a_2 = \cdots = a_n = 0$

The hard part to understand is that **functions are vectors**. You can add them, multiply them by a scalar : every property of the "usual" vectors apply to the functions

Edit : your book may also be talking about Hilbertian basis, that are a little different from algebrical basis (what I explained). In particular, with Hilbertian basis, infinite linear combinaisons are allowed